# Why can't I use Lottie in an Ionic 4 app?

Tags: angular, ionic4, lottie, bodymovin

I'm trying to get Lottie/Bodymovin' integrated into an Ionic 4 app and I'm having no luck.

Currently I'm running:

- "@ionic/angular": "4.1.0"
- "@angular/core": "~7.1.4"
- "ng-lottie": "0.3.1"

The error I'm getting is:

`ERROR DOMException: Failed to read the 'responseText' property from 'XMLHttpRequest': The value is only accessible if the object's 'responseType' is '' or 'text' (was 'json').`

I've also tried libraries such as:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-lottie
- https://chenqingspring.github.io/ng-lottie/demo/

I still get the same error.

The implementation is very straightforward, so it isn't an implementation issue.

The only other option I can really think of is importing bodymovin directly with a typings file, but I've never tried that.

I'm open to any suggestions I might not have thought of.

Comment: Have you seen this plugin which uses lottie for [animated splashscreens](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/lottie-splash-screen) - I haven't used it yet but it could be a starting point for your problem.

Comment: @rtpHarry i did try that and i get `ERROR in src/app/pages/update-item/update-item.page.ts(56,6): error TS2339: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'.`

or 

`NullInjectorError: No provider for LottieSplashScreen!`

it seems like lottie won't work in ionic 4

Answer (score 0):

The reason i got this was because i was using a faulty json file i downloaded from lottiefiles.
Once i swapped it for a new one, it worked.